# Compare only object references in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, equality

I have a numpy array of Python object. I want to compare the array against a python object and I don't want the comparison with `==` operator, but just a reference comparison is enough for my requirements.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(["abc", "def"], dtype="object")
a == "abc"
```

I am sure about my array that reference copy is enough. Let's say all strings, I have in my array are interned.

This is primarily to improve the performance when comparing zillion values. Python object comparisons are really slow.

a is "abc" won't do what I want because

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(["abc", "def"], dtype="object")

In [3]: a == "abc"
Out[3]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

In [4]: a is "abc"
Out[4]: False
```

I want the result of `a == "abc"` but I don't Python's `__eq__` method be used for the same but just the `is` operator.

Comment: After looking into it a bit, I don't think you're going to get anything that beats the list comprehension (or if you do want a numpy array as the result, the `fromiter` in my answer) in pure Python. If you want to do it in C, you can see how `==` is implemented [in this source file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c)....

Answer (score 3):

> a reference comparison is enough for my requirements

To compare object identity, use `is` instead of `==`:

```
if a is b:
   ...
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

**edit:** To apply `is` to every element of your array, you could use:

```
In [6]: map(lambda x:x is "abc", a)
Out[6]: [True, False]
```

or simply:

```
In [9]: [x is "abc" for x in a]
Out[9]: [True, False]
```

Comment: I am not sure, you got my question right. For instance


In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(["abc", "def"], dtype="object")

In [3]: a == "abc"
Out[3]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

In [4]: a is "abc"
Out[4]: False

Please see the difference in the results a == "abc" and a is "abc". I want the same result a == "abc" but I don't want python objects __eq__ method be called for same but just 'is'.

Comment: map would take a hell lot of time than a == "abc" as the result array would be a python array.

Answer (score 0):

What about with [np.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
vector_is = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x is y, otypes=[bool])
```

Then you have

```
>>> a = np.array(["abc", "def"], dtype="object")

>>> vector_is(a, "abc")
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know if you can use `operator.is_` here, because I get

```
ValueError: failed to determine the number of arguments for <built-in function is_>
```

---

This seems to be slightly slower than the list comprehension (probably because of the `lambda` calls), though it has the advantage of being a little more flexible in terms of the arguments it takes in:

```
python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np' -s 'import random, string' -s 'a = np.array(["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(4)) for e in range(100000)])' -s 'vector_is = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: x is y, otypes=[bool])' 'vector_is(a, "abcd")'
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 msec per loop

python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np' -s 'import random, string' -s 'a = np.array(["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(4)) for e in range(100000)])' -s 'vector_is = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: x is y, otypes=[bool])' '[x is "abcd" for x in a]'
100 loops, best of 3: 20 msec per loop

python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np' -s 'import random, string' -s 'a = np.array(["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(4)) for e in range(100000)])' -s 'vector_is = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: x is y, otypes=[bool])' 'np.fromiter((x is "abcd" for x in a), bool, len(a))'
10 loops, best of 3: 23.8 msec per loop
```

The last approach, `np.fromiter((x is "abcd" for x in a), bool, len(a))`, is one way to get a numpy array out of the list comprehension approach.

Unfortunately, all are much slower than just using `==`:

```
python -mtimeit -s 'import numpy as np' -s 'import random, string' -s 'a = np.array(["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(4)) for e in range(100000)])' -s 'vector_is = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: x is y, otypes=[bool])' 'a == "abcd"'                                        
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 msec per loop
```

Comment: This turns out to be slower than a == "abc" unfortunately, as it anyway would involve python method calls (which are slow).

Comment: Right -- if `operator.is_` worked, it might be faster, but `numpy.vectorize` doesn't like that for some dumb reason.